# Making horizontal scroll to stop once div ended

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a one page which has three sections. the second one needs to be scroll horizontally (e.g a products line) and then go back to vertically scroll.

I have it pretty much completed with pure JS but I'm unable to continue scrolling vertical after the second div is at the end. The this section cannot be reached.

Here is my Code Pen:https://codepen.io/yakir-mordehay/pen/XyKEgr

```js
(function() {
  function scrollHorizontally(e) {
    e = window.event || e;
    var delta = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, (e.wheelDelta || -e.detail)));
    document.getElementById('test').scrollLeft -= (delta * 40); // Multiplied by 40
    e.preventDefault();

    if ((delta > 0 && document.getElementById('test').scrollLeft > 0) || (delta < 0 && document.getElementById('test').offsetWidth + document.getElementById('test').scrollLeft < e.scrollWidth)) {

    }

  }
  if (document.getElementById('test').addEventListener) {
    // IE9, Chrome, Safari, Opera
    document.getElementById('test').addEventListener("mousewheel", scrollHorizontally, false);
    // Firefox
    document.getElementById('test').addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", scrollHorizontally, false);
  } else {
    // IE 6/7/8
    document.getElementById('test').attachEvent("onmousewheel", scrollHorizontally);
  }
})();
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: gray;
}

.view {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: lawngreen;
}

.sContainer {
  height: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.hPage {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
</script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="view">Home</div>
  <div class="sContainer" id="test">
    <div class="hPage"> view1</div>
    <div class="hPage"> view2</div>
    <div class="hPage"> view3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="view">END</div>
</div>
```

I tried to implement something like this in the JS:

```
if((delta > 0 && document.getElementById('test').scrollLeft > 0) || (delta < 0 && document.getElementById('test').offsetWidth+document.getElementById('test').scrollLeft < e.scrollWidth)) {
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

But it not working so great. It just scrolling both vertical and horizontal together.

Any ideas?

Comment: `File not found: https://s.codepen.io/boomerang/iFrameKey-18639cf3-0fd7-c19c-0a17-7e9ca53bc834/js/index.js`
    
`File not found: https://s.codepen.io/js/jquery.mousewheel.min.js`

Comment: Also please don't link to external sites for your examples. The site could go down or the link can die rendering this question useless for people that come here looking for an answer. Please update the question and use a snippet to include your example.

Comment: Thanks, added a snippet.

Comment: Thanks for updating your question and using a snippet, you still have a missing resource though, `File not found: /js/jquery.mousewheel.min.js`

Comment: Instead of recreating the wheel, maybe just take a look at [fullpage.js scroll-horizontally](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/extensions/scroll-horizontally.html)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. That is a leftover from different approach I tried (using JQuery). I also removed it from the snippet.

Comment: I'm not looking for a slide show view as in fullpage.js

Comment: Oh, your example looks like that's what you are going for. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
(function() {
  function scrollHorizontally(e) {
    e = window.event || e;
    var delta = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, (e.wheelDelta || -e.detail)));
    document.getElementById('test').scrollLeft -= (delta * 40); // Multiplied by 40
    if((delta > 0 && document.getElementById('test').scrollLeft === 0) || (delta < 0 && document.getElementById('test').offsetWidth+document.getElementById('test').scrollLeft > 3*document.getElementById('test').offsetWidth)) {

        }else{
          e.preventDefault();
        }


  }
  if (document.getElementById('test').addEventListener) {
    // IE9, Chrome, Safari, Opera
    document.getElementById('test').addEventListener("mousewheel", scrollHorizontally, false);
    // Firefox
    document.getElementById('test').addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", scrollHorizontally, false);
  } else {
    // IE 6/7/8
    document.getElementById('test').attachEvent("onmousewheel", scrollHorizontally);
  }
})();
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: gray;
}

.view {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: lawngreen;
}

.sContainer {
  height: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.hPage {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="view">Home</div>
  <div class="sContainer" id="test">
    <div class="hPage"> view1</div>
    <div class="hPage"> view2</div>
    <div class="hPage"> view3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="view">END</div>
</div>
```

```
 if((delta > 0 && document.getElementById('test').scrollLeft === 0) || (delta < 0 && document.getElementById('test').offsetWidth+document.getElementById('test').scrollLeft > 3*document.getElementById('test').offsetWidth)) {

        }else{
          e.preventDefault();
        }
```

where 3 is no. of divs of 100% width

Comment: Exactly! Thank you so much for the help!